# How to make git reset (or another method) remove empty directories?

Tags: git, command-line-arguments, tracking

I have a git repo that I need to clone, do some things, then package up and send to other people. I'm making this all automated via Ansible so there's no user intervention required.

I want to ensure that after the repo is cloned, and before it's "packaged", it gets reset to the desired state (branch/tag), thus removing any files/folders which may have been added to the local folder/working tree after it was cloned. To do this, I'm using `git reset --hard $ref`.

This does a good job at removing unwanted files, but the problem is if an empty folder was added to the repo directory, it isn't removed.

Is there a way for git to remove empty folders as well as files?

Comment: Do you mean something like `git clean`?

Comment: I do a `git reset $ref --hard` followed by a `git clean -dxf`  (where $ref is usually HEAD)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks! I didn't realize `git clean` was a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) targets tracked files/folders. So only files git is aware of. Newly created directories that weren't processed by e.g. `git add` are not included.

[`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) is something you're looking for as it targets untracked files/folders rather. Use `-d` flag to ensure recursion.